# Database Designing For Shared Data

Tags: sql, json, node.js, database, firebase

I have an interesting question. I'm currently creating an app which involves a lot of shared data. What I mean by this is that within the app, users create groups in which they store important data also visible to other people in their groups. I want to store this shared data effectively, but I'm not sure which kind of database to use. One with a JSON tree format or one with query based search?

If there's an advantage to either I would appreciate an example. I'm already familiar of Firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it all really depends on what will be the features of your app and what kind of data you would need to access, but considering a simple app with users, groups, conversations and messages, I would personally denormalize my data and use a database structure like this :

```
root/
|___ users/
|      |___ userID1
|              |___ name : user_name
|              |___ email : user_email
|              |___ picUrl : user_picture_url
|              |___ conversations
|                       |___ userConversationID1 : true                    
|                       |___ userConversationID2 : true
|                        ...
|              |___ groups
|                       |___ groupID1 : true                    
|                       |___ groupID2 : true
|                        ...
|              |___ notificationTokens
|                       |___ token1 : true                       
|                       |___ token2 : true
|                        ...
|
|___ groups/
|      |___ groupID1
|              |___ name : group_name
|              |___ thumbnailUrl : group_thumbnail_url
|              |___ conversations
|                       |___ groupConversationID1 : true                    
|                       |___ groupConversationID2 : true
|                        ...
|              |___ members
|                       |___ groupMemberID1 : true                    
|                       |___ groupMemberID2 : true
|                        ...
|
|___ conversations/
|      |___ conversationID1
|              |___ messageID1 : true
|              |___ messageID2 : true
|              |___ messageID3 : true
|              |___ messageID4 : true
|               ...
|      ...
|
|___ messages/
|      |___ messageID1
|              |___ text : message_text
|              |___ sender : message_sender
|              |___ receiver : message_receiver
|              |___ timestamp : message_timestamp
|      ...
|
|___ notifications/
|        ...
|        ...
|
```

While this structure is indeed duplicating some data, I believe it makes it easier for you to look for the user-specific or group-specific data.

For instance if you would like to get a list of all the members of the group a simple

```
Database.database().reference().child("group").child(groupId).child("members").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    // ...
 })
```

would be enough, as opposed to a nested structure where it could end up being difficult getting the data you're looking for.

If you want just let me know what kind of features do you plan to have in your app and I could be more specific. I'd be glad to help you anyway :)

**UPDATE:**

With regards to which database you should choose (relational database vs Firebase) I would say that it's directly related to the features of your app. For example if you need to sort and filter a lot of data (filter users by age, country and gender) it might be better for you to go for a SQL Database as you would be able to filter easily only the users you're looking for. While not impossible, it would be more time (and data) consuming to do it using Firebase.

Now if you build a real-time chat for example, and don't need a too complex database structure for your app then obviously Firebase would be the one you're looking for because I think it makes it really fast and easy to use.

Comment: Would there be any benefit of using a query-based search database instead

Comment: Great ! Give me a few seconds I will update my answer :)

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Glad to know this helps :) Have a great day !